# Literature for commercialisation of research

Tags: career-path

What are some good books to read for people who have been in academia their entire career (regardless of length of that career) and now want to commercialise something from their research? I am looking for tips for people who have no education in law or business, including patent rights and the business side on how to start a research-company etc.

I understand that it is a broad question, but I hope and think that it could in fact be relevant to more researchers than me.

Comment: I don't know about a good book, but, *please*, get somebody on board who has experience running a business. You are just setting yourself up to failure if you try to do this entirely on your own.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for a book (or other literature) that will teach non-business-types how to deal with all the issues in business (finance, law, competitive analysis, strategy, etc.)? You would be MUCH better off to partner with someone with that background. Imagine a business person with no experience writing software asking "Can you recommend a book that tells me how to create an ERP system?"

Answer (score 2):

Starting and running a business is an entirely different skill set from being a professor, one that takes years to learn how to do well.  You also aren't going to be able to put your whole heart into it unless you are planning to quit academia.

If you are at a research university, there is probably some sort of Technology Transfer Office filled with people who would like nothing more than to educate you on this subject.  Good TTOs will also help do matchmaking with the entrepreneurs who come to them looking for technologies to build a business around.  Your university might also have a business school.  If so, there are probably teams of students looking for new business projects and case studies.

In either case, you want to find partners who are on the same wavelength as you and who you can trust.  Commercializing has a mix of business management, finance, marketing, and technological development, and you probably want people involved who are specialists in all of those disciplines.